# Excel VBA Updating cell contents to be clickable hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

I have a register that has an edit sheet. The user selects the record they want to update and the code updates the report (Sheet "EditEx") with data from another sheet. the issue is there are a couple of links to sharepoint/folders that are a also recalled.
The sheet updates correctly (displays the full url in the required cell - "H21") however it is not a clickable hyperlink.
I just can't get it to work.

Here is the end of my code, can anyone help?
Thanks.

```
'   Refresh and unhide all rows
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Sheets("EditEx").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-120
    Rows("29:160").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("32:56").Select
    Rows("32:56").EntireRow.AutoFit
    Rows("76:105").Select
    Rows("76:105").EntireRow.AutoFit
    Rows("125:154").Select
    Rows("125:154").EntireRow.AutoFit
' ISSUE IS HERE
    Range("H21").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=Selection

'   select first input cell
    Range("C6:D6").Select

    MsgBox ("Record Retrieved. Make your changes and ensure you click 'Save Changes' to update the Master Registers")

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want do, avoid using select and selection

Comment: I'm just trying to get the contents of H21 to be a clickable link. The Cell contains a URL (in text form). My code is trying to say what ever contents is in H21, make it a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Never use selection

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("H21"), _
Address:=Range("H21").Value, _
TextToDisplay:=Range("H21").Value
```